# EC2 instance cannot connect to public IP

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I'm banging my head against the wall trying to figure out what's wrong with my EC2 VPC connectivity.  I have two EC2 instances in the same public subnet with an internet gateway.  Both instances have a public (elastic) IP address.  Instance A can ping B on its private IP address, but it cannot ping its public IP address.
I can ping B from my house just fine.

The subnet route table is like this:

| Destination | Target |
| --- | --- |
| 172.16.0.0/20 | local |
| 0.0.0.0/0 | igw-xxxxx |

Instance A is running Windows and its route table from `route print` looks correct:

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       172.16.0.1       172.16.0.9     15
```

Instance B is running Linux and I have disabled its firewall.

The B security group has an inbound rule allowing all traffic from A security group.

If I add an inbound rule to the B security group allowing all traffic from ANYWHERE then it works.  But I want to allow traffic only from A security group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allow the Elastic IP address of A on the Security Group of B (ICMP), because when you ping B with its public IP address, the traffic is not seen as being originated from the private IP address but from the public IP address.

Here is what happens:

- You type: `ping B` (public IP/EIP),
- Your VPC network tries to route the traffic to the public IP address,
- The matching route is `0.0.0.0/0 (igw-xxxxx)`
- Traffic is routed out of the VPC/AWS, and the source IP will change (NAT). So packet source IP will be `EIP` of A, and destination IP will be `EIP` of B,
- Packets get routed back to AWS

Please check AWS documentation:

> When you specify a security group as the source for a rule, traffic is allowed from the network interfaces that are associated with the source security group for the specified protocol and port. Incoming traffic is allowed based on the private IP addresses of the network interfaces that are associated with the source security group (and not the public IP or Elastic IP addresses).

Comment: Thanks, this makes perfect sense. I think I will actually switch to using the private IP in this case.

Comment: For private IP, you will need a VPN if you are accessing it from home or office.